# Wordpress problem

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Just recently, my client's blog http://robertnogueira.com/ encountered a bug. If you look at the site the footer has been displaced. It's been running fine until I tried to populate the posts for the 6th time with caff content. It got broke and I don't know how to fix it.

I chose to ask help here because the folks here usually responds to my question unlike the wordpress forums.

Please help me figure this out, I do this for a living. :(

Comment: This is not a Wordpress problem, but a HTML / CSS one. Retagged.

Comment: I don't have the time to get into it but this looks like a surrounding container being too narrow, thus not allowing the two columns to `float: left` next to each other.

Comment: @Pekka, If that's the case, then why does the problem surfaced just recently? Like I said the site has been working pretty well for 2 months until now. What could be the culprit? I tried deactivating all the plugins to no avail...

Comment: I have no idea, except that some HTML element in the content could cause trouble - you could try selectively disabling parts of the content using Firebug to find out. It could also be a missing closing tag in the content - the validator is pointing out some starting points: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Frobertnogueira.com%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way that the sidebar is underneath the content it seems that your html/css formatting got messed up.  This also could be why your footer disappeared.  Did you change anything beside adding content?  Did you change the css/html/php?

Try looking at your formatting...or what have you changed.  Could be something as simple as you having a post that is too wide (like a really long URL)

EDIT: I quick played around on firebug on you need to float your footer left:

```
float:left (get rid of your position:relative)
```

I don't know how you had your sidebar before but this is defiently a float/position problem.

EDIT2: Your sidebar is located underneath your "content-left" div tag - your sidebar should be on the same level as your content left:

```
<div.....><div id="content-left".....>....</div>
<div  id="content-right".....>....</div></div> you have the content-right nested underneath the left
```

Therefore you can fix this by floating your footer and then fixing your  tags to allow for your sidebar to float to the right and your content to the left.

Comment: Well I don't know why it broke but I posted a solution in my second edit

Comment: That fixes the placement of the footer but the sidebar is still underneath the content...

Comment: check my EDIT2 for the reason for the sidebar

Comment: I appreciate your help bvandrunen... However, they're not nested. If you look at the single and page, nothing's wrong with them and they have the same structuring.

Comment: Damn, I am sorry bvandrunen, I accidentally voted down you answer. :( 
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code errors: [[Invalid]Markup Validation of  robertnogueira.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//robertnogueira.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654), like the missing `</div>` tag. Missing `</div>` tags are the leading cause of out of place sidebars in Wordpress. Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

(And accept answers to your past questions; you have a 25% acceptance rate....)

Comment: I suspect caff content is causing all the errors. But I will look into it further..

Question: I have accepted bvandrunen's answer already. I clicked the check icon and it turned green. Did I do it right?

Comment: The errors in the validation report are in theme files, not content. What do you mean by "caff" content?

And yes, click the check icon to accept. You should go back through your old questions in your profile and accept answers, too....

Comment: caffeinated content, it's a plugin that automatically populates your blog with posts...